# Logging for Tridion windows services

Tags: web8, web8.5, sdl-tridion, logging

Version: SDL Web 8.5

I have enabled logging for below tridion windows services in lower environments, I would like to enable this in our prod environment.

- SDL Web Content Manager Service Host
- SDL Web Content Manager Search Indexer
- SDL Web Content Manager Batch Processor

Enabled logging in below config files

```
E:\SDLWeb\bin\TcmServiceHost.exe.config
E:\SDLWeb\bin\TcmSearchIndexer.exe.config
E:\SDLWeb\bin\TcmBatchProcessor.exe.config
```

Something like below

```
<loggingConfiguration name="Logging Application Block" defaultCategory="General" logWarningsWhenNoCategoriesMatch="false">
    <listeners>  
<add name="Tridion CM ServiceHost Log File" fileName="E:\SDLWeb\log\TcmServiceHost.log" formatter="Log Text Formatter" listenerDataType="Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Logging.Configuration.FlatFileTraceListenerData, Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Logging, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=349a39f202fa9b53" traceOutputOptions="None" type="Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Logging.TraceListeners.FlatFileTraceListener, Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Logging, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=349a39f202fa9b53"/>
```

and in below node

```
<categorySources>
      <add switchValue="All" name="General"/>
      <add switchValue="All" name="Tridion.ContentManager.LogCategory">
        <listeners>
          <add name="Tridion CM ServiceHost Log File" />
        </listeners>
      </add>
```

Now my questions Are

1. Performance impacts in prod?
2. How to set the log level to ERROR only?
3. How to set the log file rolling?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Performance impact depends heaviliy on the configured log level (don’t set it to Verbose on a Production env.)
2. Change the `switchValue` attribute in the log config you mentioned
3. I’m not sure if that is supported (yet) for CM logging.